# Remove redundancy lines for "almost similar" strings

Tags: bash, awk, unique, text-processing, redundancy

I have the below file:

```
ab=5
ac=6
ad=5
ba=5
bc=7
bd=4
ca=5
cb=7
cd=3
...
```

"ab" and "ba", "ac" and "ca", "bc" and "cb" are redundant.
How do I eliminate these redundant lines in bash ?

Expected output:

```
ab=5
ac=6
ad=5
bc=7
bd=4
cd=3
```

Comment: you are expected to add your own code/research effort while asking, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users... though, given interesting question, you've got plenty of answers this time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{x=substr($0,1,1); y=substr($0,2,1)} !seen[x>y?x y:y x]++' file
ab=5
ac=6
ad=5
bc=7
bd=4
cd=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Short **`awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ c1=substr($0,1,1); c2=substr($0,2,1) }!a[c1 c2]++ && !((c2 c1) in a)' file
```

- `c1=substr($0,1,1)` - assign the extracted 1st character to variable `c1`
- `c2=substr($0,2,1)` - assign the extracted 2nd character to variable `c2`
- `!a[c1 c2]++ && !((c2 c1) in a)` - crucial condition based on mutual exclusion between "similar" 2-character sequences

---

The output:

```
ab=5
ac=6
ad=5
bc=7
bd=4
cd=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one with `perl`, generic solution irrespective of number of characters before `=`

```
$ cat ip.txt
ab=5
ac=6
abd=51
ba=5
bad=23
bc=7
bd=4
ca=5
cb=7
cd=3

$ perl -F= -lane 'print if !$seen{join "",sort split//,$F[0]}++' ip.txt
ab=5
ac=6
abd=51
bc=7
bd=4
cd=3
```

- like `awk`, by default uninitialized variables evaluate to `false`
- `-F=` use `=` as field separator, results saved in `@F` array
- `$F[0]` will give first field, i.e the characters before `=`
- `split//,$F[0]` will give array with individual characters
- `sort` by default does string sorting
- `join ""` will then form single string from the sorted characters with null string as separator
- See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches for documentation on `-lane` and `-F` options. Use `-i` for inplace editing

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you, I have written and tested it with GNU `awk`.

```
awk -F'=' '{
split($1,array,"")}
!((array[1],array[2]) in a){
  a[array[1],array[2]];
  a[array[2],array[1]];
  print;
  next
}
!((array[2],array[1]) in a){
  a[array[1],array[2]];
  a[array[2],array[1]];
  print;
}
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
ab=5
ac=6
ad=5
bc=7
bd=4
cd=3
```

Comment: Using null as a field separator is undefined behavior per POSIX so only some awks (e.g. GNU awk) will split the string into characters, others will do other things.